# Stuck in a loop, or can't catch click events when using interactive.What do I need to change?

Tags: python, loops, blackjack

I am trying to make it so the user can move a IntSlider with values from 1, to their current chip count and then click the button "Place Bet" to place a bet in blackjack. I was originally using a while loop and got stuck in an infinite loop. When removing the while loop I am now not able to pickup the click event and it moves forward in the code and deals with cards with a bet of 0.

```
def take_bet(chips):
    print(f'You have {chips.total} chips to bet.')
    bet_slider = interactive(place_bet, bet = (1,chips.total,1))
    display(button)
    display(bet_slider)
    button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
    chips.bet = bet_placed


def on_button_clicked(b):
    bet_placed = bet_slider.result
    bet_slider.close()
    b.close()
    print(bet_placed)    


def run_blackjack(player_chips):
    print("Welcome to blackjack!")
    print("You start the game with 100 chips, good luck!")
    global playing
    while True:
        playing = True
        the_deck = Deck()
        the_deck.shuffle()
        player_hand = Hand()
        dealer_hand = Hand()
        dealer_hand.add_card(the_deck.deal())
        player_hand.add_card(the_deck.deal())
        dealer_hand.add_card(the_deck.deal())
        player_hand.add_card(the_deck.deal())
        take_bet(player_chips)
        show_some(player_hand, dealer_hand)

        while playing:
            hit_or_stand(the_deck, player_hand)
            show_some(player_hand, dealer_hand)
            if player_hand.value > 21:
                player_busts(player_chips)
                break
```

Comment: you have two `while` loops - which one do you mean ? If you have problem then use `print()` to check values in variables. It helps to see problem.

Comment: in the run blackjack function when it goes to take_bet(player_chips) I end up seeing an endless loop with buttons and sliders, instead of just 1. What am I doing wrong to create multiple outputs